# Has any technology been demonstrated that allows a useful payload to survive at least one month on Venus' surface?

Tags: technology, venus, environment, thermal, venera

According to the [Wikipedia article on Venera-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venera-D),

> A lander, based on the Venera design, is also planned, capable of surviving for a long duration on the planet's surface.

The surface of Venus has temperatures of 462°C and pressures of 9.2 MPa.  How can any useful payload function for more than a couple of hours in such conditions?  In the near-vacuum of space, radiators can be used to get rid of excess heat, but on Venus, the atmosphere would just radiate back, so that wouldn't work.  The only solution I can envisions is a giant, powerful, active refrigerator — and that would only address one of the problems.  I suppose one would not only need to cool down the instruments, but also external components such as solar panels (if applicable).  On the plus side, one should be able to simulate Venus conditions in a lab somewhat accurately.

Have any payloads been demonstrated (in a lab) to function for a longer time in conditions similar to the Venus surface, using active cooling with a feasible power budget?  By a longer time, I mean long enough so that mission control can interact with the spacecraft, decide what to look for based on initial results, etc.; so let's say *at least one month*.

Similar question: *[What material properties would be necessary to shield a lander from the environment of the Venusian surface?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/175/33)*.  The other question focusses on materials, whereas I specifically ask if it has been demonstrated in a lab, considering *all* aspects.

Comment: A side note: Venera-D ain't going there before 2024. Judging by the Phobos-Grount fiasco (Venera-D is done by the same team), I wouldn't place high bets on the project. BTW, WHAT **solar panels**? The lander was said to be designed for 2-3 hours only.

Comment: Venera-13 lander worked for 2 hours. Venera-14 worked for 90 minutes. That's not considered to be a reasonable time, right?

Comment: @Deer Hunter: don't judge by Phobos-Grunt alone. The very successful Spektr-R/Radioastron space telescope is essentially the very same spacecraft (modulo scientific payload).

Comment: I don't know if by *long duration* they mean to design it for hours, days, or weeks, nor how they plan to power the lander.  But my question stands regardless of what Venera-D really aims for.

Comment: @gerrit: well, the Russian version of Wikipedia says "no less than several days".

Comment: "I suppose one would not only need to cool down the instruments, but also external components such as solar panels (if applicable)."  With Venus' cloud cover, solar panels would not be practical.

Comment: @GreenMatt Are you sure?  At TOA Venus' irradiance is twice Earth, how much is left after scattering and reflection by clouds?  I'd think enough to get solar energy, considering that solar panels are used on Mars and will be used at Jupiter.

Comment: @gerrit: Spacecraft at Jupiter are in orbit, so don't have to deal with clouds. The Martian atmosphere is very thin and has fewer and thinner clouds ([Wikipedia's entry on Mars' clouds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_of_Mars#Clouds)). Venus' atmosphere is much denser, with thicker, constant cloud cover ([Wikipedia's entry on Venus' clouds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Venus#Clouds)).

Comment: @GreenMatt I know.  The question is how the irradiance at Venus+clouds compares to Mars or Jupiter without clouds.

Comment: @gerrit: Sorry, I have neither the time nor the inclination to do the research I would need to do those calculations now. If you really want to challenge this, feel free to do the work and prove me wrong. However, given that all our observations have shown constant, thick cloud cover, I find it very unlikely that solar panels would get enough light to generate useful levels of power.  (Then there's the issue of surviving the atmosphere, but that's what your question is about after all.)

Comment: I'm not claiming it either way.  Solar panels still work when cloudy, just less.  I might ask it as a seperate question, eithere here or on [Physics.SE], or search for the data myself (:

Comment: It's a well known fact in space exploration. Russian's can't have a successful Mars mission, but everything they send to Venus works. Only a slight exaggeration...

Comment: Note to those who'd like to answer: [Technology readiness level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level)

Comment: Theoretically (ignoring cost) could exotic semiconductors (computers) and magnetic materials (motors) function at such temperatures? My **wild guess** is that high temperature operation is theoretically possible but that the R&D costs required for the end result and its manufacture would be enormous with limited use outside of visiting Venus.

Comment: What do you mean by "survive Venus' surface"? Hours? Days? Weeks? Longer? Also, while you talk about temperature and pressure, don't forget that there are acidic compounds in parts of the Venusian atmosphere and any lander would have to survive those compounds in addition to the other issues.

Comment: @GreenMatt I know there are those too, I didn't mean to be complete.  I'd think that the temperature and pressure are the most challenging aspects, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @gerrit: If the acid eats your instrument before it gets to the surface ...  Anyway, more important in getting an answer to this question is specifying what you mean by survive.  Since you asked, I assume you mean more than hours, but that's not clear.  (And no, I don't have the knowledge/expertise to provide an answer, I'm just trying to help the process move along.)

Comment: @GreenMatt Okay, I've specified *at least one month*.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.sciencealert.com/nasa-has-developed-electronics-to-withstand-the-toxic-hellhole-that-is-venus

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is one area of exploration on Earth that approximates conditions on Venus, namely that of [deep oil and gas mining](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/46-04/high_temp_electronics.html), and a few additional areas of technology, near avionics engines, and even auto engines. The stated goal for such electronics is to function at 200 C or higher.

The most promising technology for surviving high temperatures is Silicon Carbide electronics, with hermetically sealed ceramic packages. These can be rated for as high as 600 C, but they aren't completely available yet.

Bottom line, it is just barely within our technology today to build something to survive on Venus (460 C), and operate at high temperatures/pressures. Likely, the solution will come from the Oil Mining Industry, where it is common to operate at high temperatures and pressures today. It will take significant engineering, but everything does in the space industry anyways.

Comment: This is half the reason I love the space industry: because of all the clever engineering solutions that are used to push it forward. The other half is just because space is so interesting itself.

Comment: http://www.sciencealert.com/nasa-has-developed-electronics-to-withstand-the-toxic-hellhole-that-is-venus

Comment: @gerrit I was right!