# How to determine heat transfer for survival on Venus?

Tags: probe, physics, venus, heat

I'm trying to determine how long a probe could survive on Venus' surface. Assuming its just a sphere of titanium with room temperature air inside, what would be the best method for determining the heat transfer between the atmosphere (superheated carbon dioxide) and the inside of the sphere? How long will it take to reach equivalent temperature?

Comment: You would do best to include heat sinks and some insulation on that thing.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration SE ! I think you could survive far more longer with a Basalt fiber sphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basalt_fiber

Comment: In the first instance, the standard formulae for thermal conductivity. You will need to know the size and thickness of the insulator (the shell), and the heat capacity of your heatsink (the volume of the air inside the shell) and, assuming your probe actually does something, the heat it generates itself

Comment: This seems more of a physics.SE question, it's about thermal dynamics not space.

Comment: Also needs convection coefficients

Comment: Related: [*Has any technology been demonstrated that allows a useful payload to survive at least one month on Venus' surface?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1269/33)

Comment: Soviet landers had a layer of thermal insulation and heat absorbers.

Comment: I think to answer this question it would beusefil to know what are the best thermal unsulation possible currently (compared with the Venera landers' insulation).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is purely a physics (heat-transfer) problem

Comment: What is the density and pressure inside the sphere ?

Comment: Assuming the sphere holds equipment designed to work on Earth, so air at room temperature and 1 atm. To those arguing to close the question, literally everything about space requires scientific/engineering principles that aren't specific to space. It doesn't really make sense to ask folks in a physics forum to help me determine the convection coefficients on Venus...

Comment: @Halen see [my comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/46869/how-to-determine-heat-transfer-for-survival-on-venus/46870?noredirect=1#comment153405_46870). I don't know the rate of heat transfer due to conduction/convection process due to contact with the atmosphere, but with no thermal ballast (just a thin shell and air) radiative heat transfer will equilibrate in 15 minutes to a few hours depending on how shiny it is in the thermal IR. This doesn't answer your question about conduction/convection but it does put things in perspective!

Comment: One comment:  is your real question about how long a probe coild survive, or a question about heat transfer?  I ask because there's one way to make the lander last longer:  Make it not care about Venus' heat.  For example, NASA has a competition for Venus rover designs that can simply operate at 900 degrees F.   such as a titanium windmill mechanically driving wheels with no electronics involved.  https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/nasa-wants-your-help-designing-a-venus-rover-concept

Comment: Also, you can use a windmill to wind springs, then use the springs to drive a clockwork computer.  The computer could record data on the equivalent of punch tape or a modern equivalent.  For sending data back to an orbiter, a clockwork mechanism could read the tape  and move a shutter back and forth across a laser reflector as it reads..  By hitting the reflector with a beam from orbit you can measure the return signal and extract the data.  It's an open question as to how  small and sophisticated we could make it all.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary**: The time will depend on how the inside of the spacecraft is insulated, but if we assume that you are in contact with the metal shell of a spacecraft similar to the lunar module (and make a lot of approximations regarding convection in the Venusian atmosphere), you will get **serious burns** within **15 minutes.** The assumptions I make break down as the temperature of the spacecraft approaches the outside temperature (convective transfer slows), but you can probably expect it to reach oven temperature (350 °F, 450 K) within two hours.

First we need to understand what kind of convective regime we are in. The atmosphere of Venus is mostly carbon dioxide (96.5% by volume?) in the supercritical phase, so I'm going to rely a lot on its properties.

Let's first compute the [Rayleigh number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_number), which tells us whether the natural convection will be turbulent.

$$\textsf{Ra} = \frac{\rho g \beta}{\eta \alpha} (T-T_\mathrm{env}) D^3$$

Here is the data I'm using.
Atmospheric density: $\rho =  65~\mathrm{kg/m^3}$ [(source)](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html)
Acceleration of gravity: $g = 8.87~\mathrm{m/s^2}$ [(source)](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html)
Temperature of environment: $T_\mathrm{env} = 737~\mathrm{K}$ [(source)](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html)
Temperature of spacecraft surface: $T = 294~\mathrm{K}$
Film temperature (used in calculating the quantities below): $T_f = (T + T_\mathrm{env})/2 = 515.5~\mathrm{K}$
Thermal expansion coefficient at $515.5~\mathrm{K}$: $\beta = 0.00194~\mathrm{K}^{-1}$ (ideal gas law)
Atmospheric pressure: $p = 92~\mathrm{bar}$ [(source)](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/venusfact.html)
Dynamic viscosity of CO<sub>2</sub> at 515.5 K and 92 bar: $\eta = 2.50 \times 10^{-5}~\mathrm{N \cdot s/m^2}$ [(source)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.supflu.2010.12.006) 
Thermal conductivity of CO<sub>2</sub> at 100 bar and 450 K: $k = 0.03392~\mathrm{W/(m \cdot K)}$ [(source)](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/carbon-dioxide-thermal-conductivity-temperature-pressure-d_2019.html) 
Isobaric specific heat of CO<sub>2</sub> at 500 K: $c_p = 1014~\mathrm{J/(kg \cdot K)}$ [(source)](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/carbon-dioxide-d_974.html)
Thermal diffusivity of atmosphere: $\alpha = k/(\rho c_p) = 5.15 \times 10^{-7}~\mathrm{m^2/s}$ 
Characteristic size: $D = 6~\mathrm{m}$

I end up with $\mathsf{Ra} = 8.33\times 10^{15}$, which is more than sufficient for [Rayleigh–Bénard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93B%C3%A9nard_convection) convection cells to form.

I can't find relations for [heat transfer coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) for a sphere, so I'm just going to treat the spacecraft as a horizontal plate. Our Rayleigh number is also out of the range of validity for this equation (supposed to be $<3\times10^{10}$), but I'm going to ignore that too.

$$h = \frac{0.27 k}{D}\,\mathsf{Ra}^{1/4} \sim 1.5~\mathrm{W/(K \cdot m^2)}$$

How long this takes for this heat transfer coefficient to kill you will depend a lot on the interior structure of the spaceship and possibly convection inside the spaceship. You will survive a lot longer if you are in the center of the spaceship surrounded by foam insulation. I don't really want to try to address that, so let's just assume your body is in contact with the titanium shell. I'm also going to ignore the fact that the convection field outside the spacecraft will dissipate as it cools off (you will probably die before that effect is significant anyway). The specific heat of titanium also changes as it warms up, but let's just use a constant value.

Specific heat of Ti: $c = 0.52~\mathrm{J/(g \cdot K)}$
Spacecraft area: $A= 113~\mathrm{m}^2$
Spacecraft thickness: $L = 1.5~\mathrm{cm}$
Density of Ti: $L = 4.5~\mathrm{g/cm^3}$
Spacecraft mass: $AL\rho_\mathrm{Ti}$ = $2545~\mathrm{kg}$ (similar to dry mass of the lunar module ascent stage)

The characteristic time for [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling) is:
$$\tau = \frac{mc}{hA} \approx 130.1~\mathrm{minutes}$$

The temperature of the spacecraft shell as a function of time is:
$$T(t) = T_\mathrm{env} + \left( T(0) - T_\mathrm{env} \right) \mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau}$$

The time at which the spacecraft shell reaches a temperature $T$ in kelvin is:
$$t_T = -\tau \ln \left( \frac{737-T}{443}\right)$$

[Burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_burn) develop on skin within a second for temperatures above 343 K, so you will start getting severe burns on any portion of your body in contact with the spacecraft shell within **15 minutes**.

Edit: I'm also ignoring wind. [Winds at the surface of Venus are supposed be pretty still](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.icarus.2015.09.036) ($<2~\mathrm{m/s}$). But if there are high winds, expect to roast more quickly.

Comment: Wow, so the heat transfer between a gas and a solid surface can be at least estimated simply from the conductivity of the gas itself, plus $\mathsf{Ra}$ and some $D$.  $$h =\frac{0.27 k}{D}\,\mathsf{Ra}^{1/4}$$ What is $D$ and why 6 meters? This gets the coveted `+n!` upvote award btw

Comment: @uhoh It started out being roughly the size of my office, but it's also roughly the size of the lunar module. (7.04 m * 4.22 m * 9.4 m)^(1/3) = 6.5 m

Comment: Ah, I see, $\frac{\mathsf{Ra}^{1/4}}{D} \sim D^{-1/4}$ is almost independent of size; it's not a big effect

Comment: @uhoh That's an interesting point. I guess the strongest contributor is the conductivity $k$, which contributes $k^{3/4}$.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems primarily interested in the rate of heat transfer from Venus to the spherical <s>cow</s> spacecraft via conduction and convection types of transfer. That includes both inelastic collisions of atmospheric molecules with the sphere and also adhesion of hot particulates and/or droplets of any aerosol if that happens.

The high density of the atmosphere means that atomic collisions will happen about 160x more frequently than in Earth's atmosphere; 100x more due to density and 1.6x more due to speed (flux ~ areal density x velocity).

This kind of calculation is central to engineering any aerocraft or lander that may go to bodies with atmospheres. In addition to hot ones like Venus there are cold ones like Titan; either way there's heat transfer from the craft to the environment and it's very important to have a realistic estimate.

That being said, *I don't know!*

However, the [Stefan–Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) $\sigma$ is 5.67E-8 W/m<sup>2</sup>/K<sup>4</sup> It's the only constant besides pi that I can remember four digits of off the top of my head, because it's got 5, 6, 7, 8

and the [Stefan–Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) says that a sphere of radius $R$ will receive a *radiant power* of something of the order of

$$4\pi R^2 \sigma T^4$$

A sphere with a volume of 1 cubic meter has a diameter of 1.24 meters. That's about the same size as a one ton spherical cow.

It has an area of about 4.84 square meters. Thinking of the Venusian surface and atmosphere as a blackbody cavity, there will be **73 kilowatts of radiant power** incident on our <s>cow</s> sphere!

If it's fairly highly reflective over most of its area, maybe one can get that down to 10 kW (a surface-averaged reflectivity of thermal IR of 85%). It's going to have to be smooth, shiny metal, to do that, and the metal will have to withstand Venus' chemical environment.

If our sphere were indeed a spherical cow with the heat capacity of water needing 4200 Joules for each kg to be raised by one degree, then our spacecraft would warm one degree every 7 minutes, or 100 degrees per every 11.7 hours.

Make all of that 7 times shorter if the spacecraft is dark/absorbing for thermal IR.

While not the central theme of the question, the other answers that will hopefully be posted can be compared to this.

Comment: not related: [Radiative Properties of the Skin and Haircoat of Cattle and Other Animals](https://elibrary.asabe.org/abstract.asp?aid=13567) and [Thermal balance of Nellore cattle](https://europepmc.org/article/med/28421269) and [Environmental parameters to assessing of heat stress in dairy cattle—a review](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00484-018-1629-9)

Comment: @Uwe I've addressed exactly that within the question: "That being said, I don't know!" and "While not the central theme of your question, the other answers that will hopefully be posted can be compared to this." We're both looking forward to better answers!

Comment: In a comment the questioner confirms that inside the sphere there's mostly air at room temperature and 1 atm.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace Thanks. hmm... well then a 5 mm thick titanium wall is 22.5 kg/m^2 and it takes 540 Joules to raise 1 kg by 1 Kelvin, or 12 kJ/m^2. The raw IR flux is 16.7 kJ/sec (kW) so if the shell is dark it will heat about 1.3 K/sec! at first. Of course it will slow down because it's an exponential and the rate that the shell radiates back becomes significant (the rate is really $\sigma (T_{venus}^4 - T_{sphere}^4)$ so it will equilibrate most of the way in about 15 minutes if dark, and a few hours if shiny. The air inside does nothing to slow it down, that's why I added water.

Comment: Impressive calculations ! I've looked for answers on Physics SE for conductive heating of spheres, but it got to complicated for me. I think you could handle this !

Comment: @Cornelisinspace those Physics folks like to "sound smart" sometimes. Ya for a thick wall where the inner diameter is substantially different than the outer diameter, the heat flow differential equation looks more complicated. But for a thin shell of a good pure metal like Ti the equilibration time from outside to inside is just seconds so all that stuff can be ignored. For a thick steel sphere, it's gonna be a lot slower and heat diffusion will have to be treated more carefully.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I learned this the hard way in shop class a million years ago. We made chisels from hexagonal steel stock first with a furnace, anvil and hammer, then using a grinding wheel to make it sharp. You could hold one end in your hands while grinding the other end until it got so hot it turned blue from oxidation. Years later I tried to grind one end of an *aluminum* rod holding the other end in my hand, screamed and almost burned myself, conductivity of a metal like aluminum is far higher than steel. Ti is not very high, but this is only 5mm vs 20 cm.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace looks like the area 4.84 m^2 is correct but I left off the 4 in the expression; feel free edit & fix, thanks!

Comment: @Cornelisinspace "...then **our spacecraft** would warm one degree every 7 minutes... Make all of that 7 times shorter if the spacecraft is dark/absorbing for thermal IR." The idea being that they would have tried to make it mostly reflective so it would fry (or boil) too quickly.